# How to format a Vertica date column into just the month?

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to format a Vertica date column into only the month.

I would need the final value in some sort of date datatype so in the report I can order the results by date/time, not order by text.  So that February sorts after January etc.

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(purchase_date), 'Month')  
from transactions
order by 1;
```

I am also tried:

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(MONTH(purchase_date)), 'Month')  
from transactions
order by 1;
```

The above statements produce an error "Invalid value for Month"

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give examples of the output you are trying to get?

Comment: Why do you try to convert a single "month" back to a date? That doesn't make sense. Another option might be `extract(month from purchase_date)` which is ANSI SQL but I don't know if Vertica supports it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff<br>
January - 10 sales<br>
February - 20 sales<br>

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, so the rows sort in month/date order

Comment: In general, for formatting questions, Vertica does it the same way as PostgreSQL. So if you can't find an answer for Vertica, do an Internet search for how it is done in PostgreSQL and it will most likely be the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
select to_char(purchase_date, 'Month')
from transactions
order by purchase_date;
```

You can order by columns that are not in the `select` list.

EDIT:

If you want to combine months from multiple years, the above will not work quite right.  This will:

```
select to_char(purchase_date, 'Month')
from transactions
order by extract(month from purchase_date);
```

Comment: It was not I that downvoted it, I dont know who did.

Comment: @davidjhp . . . That wasn't my question.  Does this approach work for you?

Comment: to_char wont work since then it wont sort in date order, So that February sorts after January etc.

Comment: @davidjhp . . . It isn't sorting by the results of `to_char()`, it is sorting by the original date.

Comment: The actual query is a large group by statement, I highly simplified it for SO, but the real query is larger.  PS thanks for the effort.

Comment: @davidjhp . . . I suspected as much.  In that case, use `order by max(purchase_date)`.  You can put the month name in the `select` and that will put things in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select TO_CHAR((NOW() - INTERVALYM '1 MONTH'), 'MON');
```

Output:

```
JUN
```

This will help you get only the name of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly use date_part to get a month from the timestamp.

```
SELECT DATE_PART('MONTH', purchase_date) purchase_date
```

TO_DATE gives the complete date, if you only provide MM in the parameter then Vertica set default year and day.

Let suppose the month number is 8.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(purchase_date, 'MM')
```

> Output: (0001-08-01)